# Syntax error for a script requiring 3 specific read variables?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have to hand write responses to a script that is already given to me. The two sets of information I have to give an output for are if the variables that will be read are 3 3 3, and 20 3 5.

I decided to test the script first, but keep having syntax errors on line 19, and can't figure out what the issue is. I have tested multiple variants of the spacing and parenthesis, but can't quite get there. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/sh
## Name of the program is challengelab3.2

## request information from the user
echo enter 3 numbers
read a b c

## check for proper range of numbers
if [ $a -gt 10 -o $b -gt 10 -o $c -gt 5 ]; then
    echo "numbers out of range"
    exit 1
fi

# process_data
x=$(($a + $b + $c))

while [ $x -gt 0 ]
do
     echo (( $x / 2%2 ))
     x=$((expr $x -1))
done

# end of program
```

Comment: `x=$((expr $x -1))` should either be arithmetic `((x--))` or command substitution with single parentheses `x=$(expr $x -1)` -- however `sh` does not have arithmetic expressions built-in, so either use bash or ksh, or stick to `expr` everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
## Name of the program is challengelab3.2

## request information from the user
echo enter 3 numbers
read a b c

[ -z "$a" ] && echo a is missing, enter all 3 numbers && exit 1
[ -z "$b" ] && echo b is missing, enter all 3 numbers && exit 1
[ -z "$c" ] && echo c is missing, enter all 3 numbers && exit 1

if [ "$a" -gt 10 -o "$b" -gt 10 -o "$c" -gt 5 ]; then
    echo "numbers out of range"
    exit 1
fi

# process_data
x=$((a + b + c))

while [ "$x" -gt 0 ]
do
    echo $(( x / 2 % 2 ))
    x=$((x - 1))
done
```

1. shell arithmetic is done with `$(( ... ))`
2. Remember to quote your variables outside of `$(())` and `[[ ]]`.  Without the quotes, if $a or $b or $c are undefined (e.g. user enters only 1 or 2 numbers) there will be a syntax error because `-gt` requires two operands.

Comment: The -o syntax is perfectly valid, it will throw errors if $a $b or $ are non-numeric or blank, as will your code. - this comment refers to your answer before it was completely changed(!)

Comment: line 20: expr 9 -1: syntax error in expression (error token is "9 -1")  is what I am getting from the changes you have posted so far

Comment: Very good cas +1! Jake26x, you could debug your bash code with #!/bin/sh -xv  to get more help.

Comment: My final output from the given code corrections using variables 3 3 3 for read was

3 3 3 (on one line) 
0
0
1
1
0
0
1
1
0